# How to Iterate through multiple strings in an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I have an array of strings.

```
a = "Apple Banana oranges grapes. free free free phones. deals deals time.black white grey"
b = a.split(/\./)
```

I want to check if a word `"free"` or `"deals"` is present in each string, and count and store it to a new array.

```
c = 0
d = 0
g = Array.new
t = Array.new
b.each do |i|
  if /free/.match(i)
    t.push i
    c = c + 1
  elsif /deals/.match(i)
    t.push i
    d = d + 1
  else
    g.push i
  end
end
p d
p c
p g
p t
```

But it doesn't show the exact count. Is there any other way to parse a string inside an array?

Comment: Can you clarify what your expected output is? You want to show the count of `deals` and the count of `free` in the first string? Would `p a.split.count "deals"` work?

Answer (score 0):

With a little variable renaming, and some trickery of `scan` instead of match, this might work?

```rb
a = "Apple Banana oranges grapes. free free free phones. deals deals time.black white grey"
sentences = a.split(/\./) # Split on `.`

# Initialize variables
free_count = 0
deal_count = 0
no_match = []
matches = []

sentences.each do |i| # Go through each sentence
  if (m = i.scan(/free/)) && m.any? # Try matching "free", and check if there is any matches
    matches << i # Add match to matches array
    free_count += m.length # Count up amounts of `free` spotted.
  elsif (m = i.scan(/deals/)) && m.any? # Try matching "deals", and check if there is any matches
    matches << i # Add match to matches array
    deal_count += m.length # Count up amounts of `deals` spotted.
  else
    no_match << i # Count up for nothing spotted
 end
end

p free_count #=> 3
p deal_count #=> 2
p no_match #=> ["Apple Banana oranges grapes", "black white grey"]
p matches #=> [" free free free phones", " deals deals time"]
```

Comment: Thank you,On another note- Could you tell me a way by which we can iterate a string within an array of multiple strings ?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach counts the sentences, not the occurrences of a word in the matched sentences. Use `c += i.split.count "free"` to count the actual occurrences of the word `"free"`. Avoid using single-letter variable names unless the meaning is clear.

However, this all seems like a bit of extra lifting; you can perform counts and select/reject items matching a pattern using [builtin array methods](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html):

```
a = "Apple Banana oranges grapes. free free free phones. deals deals time.black white grey"

p a.split(".").grep /\bfree\b|\bdeals\b/
p a.split(".").reject {|e| e =~ /\bfree\b|\bdeals\b/}
p a.split.count "free"
p a.split.count "deals"
```

Output:

```
[" free free free phones", " deals deals time"]
["Apple Banana oranges grapes", "black white grey"]
3
2
```

[Try it!](https://repl.it/repls/UrbanEnlightenedJavadocs)

Comment: Thank you,On another note- Could you tell me a way by which we can iterate a string within an array of multiple strings ?

Comment: In Ruby, there are probably dozens of ways of doing that. You can use `.each` on arrays and `.each_char` on a string to iterate characters.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a solution that follows your original code:

```
a = "Apple Banana oranges grapes. free free free phones. deals deals time.black white grey"
b = a.split(/\W+/)

c = 0
d = 0
g = Array.new
t = Array.new
b.each do |i|
  if i == "free"
    t.push i
    c = c + 1
  elsif i == "deals"
    t.push i
    d = d + 1
  else
    g.push i
  end
end

puts "Original words: #{b}"
puts "Counts of 'free': #{c}"
puts "Counts of 'deals': #{d}"
puts "Array of matches: #{t}"
puts "Array of non matches: #{g}"
```

And the output is:

```
# Original words: ["Apple", "Banana", "oranges", "grapes", "free", "free", "free", "phones", "deals", "deals", "time", "black", "white", "grey"]
# Counts of 'free': 3
# Counts of 'deals': 2
# Array of matches: ["free", "free", "free", "deals", "deals"]
# Array of non matches: ["Apple", "Banana", "oranges", "grapes", "phones", "time", "black", "white", "grey"]
```

---

An example of counting using Ruby tools:

```
counts = {}
a.split(/\W+/).tap { |b| b.uniq.map { |w| counts[w.downcase] = b.count(w) } }
counts #=> {"apple"=>1, "banana"=>1, "oranges"=>1, "grapes"=>1, "free"=>3, "phones"=>1, "deals"=>2, "time"=>1, "black"=>1, "white"=>1, "grey"=>1}
```

Then you can access data, for example:

```
counts.keys #=> ["apple", "banana", "oranges", "grapes", "free", "phones", "deals", "time", "black", "white", "grey"]
counts['free'] #=> 3
counts['deals'] #=> 2
counts.select { |_, v| v > 1} #=> {"free"=>3, "deals"=>2}
```